# How can I find which device is using all my network bandwidth?

Tags: networking, router

Can someone please help me eliminate a problem within my house? There is a device in my house which continues to use all of my router's bandwidth.

How can I find which device it is which is using all of my bandwidth?

I have the Virgin Media Super Hub 3 Router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consumer grade routers do not usually provide per-connected-device statistics.

Disconnect one device and then monitor available bandwidth. Reconnect that device and repeat with the next until all devices have been checked. If the bandwidth improves when a particular device is disconnected then you have found your culprit. (If not, you may have more than one device consuming excessive bandwidth and will have to try more complex combinations.)